# Null terminating char array in C and difference between using read and fgets

Tags: c, fgets

I did something like this to read from standard input.

```
char *lines[50];
char buffer[50];

while((fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))!=NULL) {
    buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
    lines[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer));
    memcpy(lines[i++], buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

I wanted to do something similar using the `read` system call.

```
while((nread=read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer)))>0) {
    buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
    lines[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer));
    memcpy(lines[i++], buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

Resetting i to 0 and printing out the strings using `printf("%s", lines[i])`, I get correct results for the first method but do not always corresponding results in the second method. Why is this?

Also, when reading from standard input using read, is it necessary to append a null character to the end of the string or does read do it for you?

I directed input from a file containing the following:

```
This is test input
This is another test input

Not reading correctly, not reading correctly
```

When I print after getting input using `fgets()` I get the exact same as output.

When I print after getting input using `read()` I get this:

```
This is test input
This is another test input

Not
reading correctly, not reading correctly
put

No
```

---

ADDITIONAL NOTES:

If I change `char buffer[50]` to something larger, the second case works, but I don't see why it shouldn't work for this particular instance.

The problem seems to be that `read` reads all 50 characters when I redirect input from a file. Is there some way that read can read up to a newline character and stop there on each iteration? It seems to do this when receiving input from the console.

Comment: You need to allocate space for the `NULL` character with your call to `malloc()` and ensure that after the call to `memcpy` you NULL-terminate. The length returned by `strlen()` doesn't include the NULL.

Comment: `lines[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);memcpy(lines[i++], buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);`

Comment: It is not loading up to newline in case of `read`. NUL also not added.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY. When I print `nread` for the input `this` it says 5.

Comment: but `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';`, `strlen(buffer)` wrong. and   `nread` is updated each time the loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY. Also when I print strlen(buffer), I get 6. Also when I print the string I get a new line. If I do `buffer[strlen(buffer)-2] = '\0'` I don't get a new line. That seems to be the end of the string. I think read appends a null character to the end.

Comment: @Zaphod. `buffer` is _not_ NULL-terminated. Therefore, you can't pass it to `strlen()`.

Comment: be read by `read` can be terminated at 0 is not guaranteed.

Comment: Please use `strdup()` instead of code like `lines[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer)); memcpy(lines[i++], buffer, strlen(buffer));` to avoid errors like forgetting to null terminate the duplicated string.  Not to mention it's just plain easier to read.

Comment: After a successful `fgets()`, `buffer` always end with `'\0'`.  It might not end with `'\n'`, `'\0'` though.  So doing `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';` is not a good way to deal with a potential `'\n'`. Suggest `size_t len = strlen(buffer);         if (len > 0 && buf[len-1] == '\n') buf[--len] = '\0';`

Comment: @Michael Burr Agree `strdup()` is easier to read, but it is not part of the C spec - unfortunately.

Comment: @chux: neither is `read()`.  But if `strdup()` isn't acceptable, then a custom version should be written as a project's utility function (appropriately ifdef`ed or given an alternate name).

Comment: @Michael Burr Agree on both points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`read` doesn't add anything; there is no terminating 0. After `read`, `strlen(buffer)` returns whatever depending on what was there in the buffer before `read`. Good news are, you don't need to call `strlen` at all, because `read` returns a number of characters transmitted:

```
while((nread = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1))>0) {
    buffer[nread] = '\0';
    lines[i] = malloc(nread + 1));
    memcpy(lines[i], buffer, nread + 1);
}
```

PS: Don't forget to test `nread` against -1.

Comment: Also increment `i` otherwise you'll overwrite the previous line each time.

Comment: Whether I use `strlen(buffer)` or `nread` shouldn't make a difference to the output as long as I add or subtract from these quantities appropriately.

Comment: @Zaphod. `strlen()` expects it is passed a NULL terminated string. `buffer` is _not_ NULL terminated. `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';` I don't think I can make it any clearer.

Comment: @user58697 To make a bit more clear, avoid the uppercase `NULL` when referring to the null character or `'\0'` given that C uses `NULL` as the null pointer.

Comment: @Zaphod user58697 is correct in saying that after a `read()`, `buffer` is _not_ known to have any `'\0'` in it.  Should code want to work with it as a C string, appending a `'\0'` is a good idea.

Comment: Change the last two lines to a call to `strdup()`.  It's a nice simple function call for something that should be a nice simple function call instead of a couple messy expressions that are easy to get details incorrect in.

Comment: @user58697. Was printing some outputs and I came up with the same answer as yours. However, I wanted to store each line in it's own string. I guess this is not possible when using `read`? It is possible if I'm inputting from the keyboard but not from a file.

Comment: @Zaphod `read` is not line oriented; its primary purpose is to read binary data. Reading lines (in a sense of `\n`) with `read` is probably not the best idea. You would have to search the buffer for a newline, and then figure out what to do with the rest of data.